# Changing the default schema of a user

Tags: oracle, schema

In order for an application user (APP_USER) to use another schema (SCHEMA_OWNER) without the need for prefixing queries with the schema name, I have [implemented a logon trigger that changes the session parameter CURRENT_USER](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/schema-owners-and-application-%20users.php#current_schema_approach).

This works fine except for sequences. When I do either of

```
select my_seq.nextval from dual;
insert into foo(bar) values(my_seq.nextval);
```

... I get the error

```
SQL Error [1031] [42000]: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Any ideas on why this may be and how to solve it?

Two possibilties comes to mind, maybe I need to

1. grant select privileges to SYS.DUAL of SCHEMA_OWNER? or
2. use the SESSION_USER instead of the deprecated CURRENT_USER parameter/variable?

Unfortunately I do not have admin rights on the database, else I would test it myself. I must work through a DBA, which means I have some difficulty in trying out different solutions and ask the question here in the hope to speed up the process.

*Please note that workarounds like creating Oracle synonyms or views is not an option and likewise I cannot prefix all queries with the schema name since the application is a packaged product. Running as the schema owner is not an option either because of enterprise policy.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you don't have SELECT access on the sequence. Ask the DBA to run:

`GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA_OWNER.MY_SEQ TO APP_USER;`

Can you edit your post with the full error message you're receiving?

Regarding your comment. I suspect you've got `SELECT ANY TABLE` etc privs. These don't apply to sequences, as demonstrated below:

```
PHIL@PHILL11G2 > create user test1 identified by test1;

User created.

PHIL@PHILL11G2 > grant connect,select any table to test1;

Grant succeeded.

PHIL@PHILL11G2 > create sequence testseq;

Sequence created.

PHIL@PHILL11G2 > conn test1/test1;
Connected.
Loading glogin.sql

Session altered.

TEST1@PHILL11G2 > select count(*) from phil.bigtable;

  COUNT(*)
----------
   2300640

TEST1@PHILL11G2 > 

TEST1@PHILL11G2 > select phil.testseq.nextval from dual;
select phil.testseq.nextval from dual
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Comment: *Added literal error message*. Yes, making sure that there are enough privileges is definitely worth trying but I do believe APP_USER has general select, update, insert and delete privileges to the  SCHEMA_OWNER schema. E.g. If I as SCHEMA_OWNER create a new table I do not have any problems using it from APP_USER.

Comment: Yes, could very well be it! I will wait with marking the answer as accepted until I have actually tried it (Given the time a roundtrip with the DBA takes it may be a couple of days or so...)

Comment: See this Q if you want to check what's granted to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298473/how-can-i-list-all-grants-a-user-received

Comment: You could setup Oracle XE http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/overview/index.html to quickly test/verify these things so you know they will work.

Comment: Problem solved, it was a simple case of not having the right privileges. Thanks a lot for input!

Comment: No worries. Visit again ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could consider allowing `APP_USER` to [proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/authentication.htm#sthref405) as `SCHEMA_OWNER`:

```
ALTER USER SCHEMA_OWNER GRANT CONNECT THROUGH APP_USER;
```

Then you can connect as `APP_USER[SCHEMA_OWNER]` using the `APP_USER` password and it will behave as though you are logged in as `SCHEMA_OWNER` for schema references, permissions, and almost everything except database links.

Comment: Good call. +1 from me

Comment: Well, if all (most) permissions are inherited that basically defeats the purpose of having an application user in the first place. The whole idea is to give limited access to the SCHEMA_OWNER schema.

Comment: Indeed, it does provide full access to the capabilities (permissions) of `SCHEMA_OWNER`.  My impression was that `APP_USER` had permissions on most things in `SCHEMA_OWNER`.  If this is not the case then proxying would not be a good option.  Note that if `APP_USER` did have full permissions on `SCHEMA_OWNER`, there is a benefit to proxying over just using the `SCHEMA_OWNER` user directly.  Specifically, being able to identify `APP_USER` is beneficial in logs, auditing, etc.